# Why can't I update wxPython's StaticText?

Tags: python, function, text, attributes, wxpython

I'm writing a calculator using wxPython for the GUI. I've made a class called display to use StaticText to display the text. Anyways, when I try to update the screen, it raises an exception.
Here's the code:

```
class display:
    def __init__(self,parent, id):
        print "display class is working"
        global string1
        self.view = wx.StaticText(frame, -1, "Waiting", (30,7), style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

    @staticmethod
    def update(self):
        global string1
        self.view.SetLabel(string1)
```

Whenever I try to run the Update() function, it raises this exception:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'view'
```

When I wrote "self.view = wx. etc etc", I tried to set the StaticText to a variable name, so I could use the SetLabel function. The text seems to work until I try to update it. Why can't I update it? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

@staticmethods take no arguments ... so its not actually getting self ... you need to either make it a @classmethod which gets cls  or you need to just make it a normal method

```
class display:
    view = None
    def __init__(self,parent, id):
        print "display class is working"
        global string1
        display.view = wx.StaticText(frame, -1, "Waiting", (30,7), style = wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)

    @classmethod
    def update(cls):
        global string1
        cls.view.SetLabel(string1)
```